# How do I Scrape and Iterate Through a Table from Website in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape and iterate through a table in Python and then input it into a pandas DataFrame, but I am having trouble even finding the table using BeautifulSoup. This is what I normally do, but there does not seem to be a table within the source code. How would I pull the main table on this page?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

url = 'https://markets.ft.com/data/director-dealings'
site = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')

print(table)
```

I also have no idea how to iterate through the table, so if you could give me some pointers on that, it would be much appreciated as well.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no table in the page

Comment: you need a subscription to enter the site? We can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

That is because there is no table tag on the URL you are loading. Go to the URL and view the source then search on "<table" you will find that there are no results

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I would be able to pull the information if it isn't in the source code?

Answer (score 0):

when you get the table, define the HTML tag of the table as a dictionary `dict` or a list `list` such as "tablex"
after that you may do the following

```
for x in tablex:
    #x represents each item from the table
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the data in a link

```
link='xyz_xyz.com'
tables_on_page = pd.read_html(link)
i=0
while i<len(tables_on_page):
   print(tables_on_page[i])
   i=i+1
```